# Can the terms 'variable' and 'field' be used interchangeably in java?

Tags: java, variables, field

While studying java with several books, none of them seem to make it clear when to use which term. 
Right now I understand it as follows:

Variables are defined within a method, while fields are part of a class.

Comment: And "fields" is often used interchangeably with "properties"

Comment: Just like usually Function == Method.

Comment: @Tnay - not always. I've often seen "function" used to describe a function that returns values, while "methods" are void. But they are often used interchangeably.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a *method* is associated with an instance of an object, while a *function* is not. Hence, you have static functions, but instance methods.

Comment: I've looked it up in the spec. It's all in section `4.12`. It says "A **variable** is a storage location and has an associated type, sometimes called its compile-time type, that is either a primitive type (§4.2) or a reference type (§4.3)." and "A class variable is a **field** declared using the keyword static within a class declaration or with or without the keyword static within an interface declaration..." and "An instance variable is a **field** declared within a class declaration without using the keyword static...". A variable can be named (eg fields) or unnamed (eg array components).

Comment: @Anon Then again, languages like JavaFX have instance functions xD

Comment: Thx everybody for your immediate help!
That was a great welcome to the stackoverflow :)

Comment: froadie: but a field is something very different from a property. A property is usually a Java Bean property (i.e. it has a getter and/or a setter). A field is definitely a field. It can be used to implement a property, but it *is not* a property itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:

You have the right idea.

After going back to the Java Documentation, I'll use [their terminology](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html):

- Member variables in a class—these are called fields.
- Variables in a method or block of code—these are called local variables.
- Variables in method declarations—these are called parameters.

Variables refer to fields, local variables, and parameters.

Answer (score 4):

"Variables" is a more general term than "fields". But your summation is basically correct. A field *is* a class-level variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Variables can be be local to a method. Fields are variables that belong to the class.

**EDIT** : Fields can be `private`, `protected`, or `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Fields are also called members.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right to stress the difference. A variable is something that can change, a field is rather a member that has a value, this value can be final in which case calling it a variable seems a bit strange.

Comment: Any variable, including a local variable, can be final.

Comment: Interestingly in Scala, we don't have the final keyword, instead we declare variable with `var` and final value with `val`.

Answer (score -1):

In java, a variable is anything which **can** change its value over the period of execution, while a field (which can also be called a "member" variable of a class) belongs to a class.

A constant/final can be though of (although some may disagree) as opposite of variable.

A Field belongs to a class and can be a variable or constant/final.